# htaccess rewrite 3 conditions to real domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write a short htaccess script that will rewrite the following conditions, but I want it to do so for the whole website, not just the homepage.

EG.

- domain.com redirects to www.domain.org
- www.domain.com redirects to www.domain.org
- domain.org redirects to www.domain.org

Note, it needs to work so all pages of the site are forced to the www.domain.org domain. For example,

domain.org/contact-us/ redirects to  www.domain.org/contact-us/

and

domain.com/about/ redirects to  www.domain.org/about/

etc etc

Appreciate your help.

Matt

Answer (score 1):

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain.com|www.domain.com|domain.org)
>   RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

Comment: The 301's a good call so it becomes a permanent redirect to search engines and browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^example.com(.*)$     [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www.example.com(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.example.org$1        [R]
```